# SwiftUI, UIViewController banner wrapper consumes too much space

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, admob

Integrating `AdMob` into a `SwiftUI` app, the Google sample code utilizes a `UIViewController` to display banner ad. The banner view, stretches to the maximum possible height, causing display issues. the following code demonstrates the issues:

```swift
struct SomeScreen: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Some text")
            Spacer()
            BannerContentView(navigationTitle: "Banner").background(.red)   
        }
    }
}
```

`BannerContentView` implementation is taken from here: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/blob/main/Swift/advanced/SwiftUIDemo/SwiftUIDemo/Banner/BannerContentView.swift (Copy / Pasted)

As can be seen in the screenshot, the `BannerContentView` consumes as much space as possible, having the `Spacer()` have no effect. How can I modify `BannerContentView` which inherits `UIViewController` to take only the space required by the banner?

[image]